# How can I move commits to a later branch and avoid reverting them when merging?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

Background: We're making the switch over to GIT in an enterprise workspace, and are keen to have the best habits.  We've decided to adopt **GitFlow** as our workflow, but it doesn't explain reverting changes that need to be pulled at the last minute.

We created our release branch `release/1.1.0`.  But this contains several commits that we do not want to release into production yet.

I suspect that if I were to use `git revert` to take out these commits,  when I reintegrate the release branch back into `master`, those commits would then be removed.

In GIT and/or GitFlow, what is the *correct* practice for pulling a commit out of a release, so that it doesn't get reverted later?

Comment: What do you mean by `so that it doesn't get reverted later?"  This is non-standard language for Git.

Comment: Fair enough - I mean so that it doesn't get removed later.  So I take out a commit... in SVN world (so to speak), if I merged the branches, the 'revert' or removal of a change would be applied to the original branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently remove entire commits from your `release/1.1.0` branch, the correct tool to use is:

`git rebase -i`

```
git checkout release/1.1.0
git rebase -i
```

You will be prompted with something looking like this:

```
pick a8xl3do Comment for commit c1
pick 49Un2Sa Comment for commit c2
pick d0a9iUl Comment for commit c3
pick G38c8oA Comment for commit c4
```

Git will give you a list of options, including the following comment:

```
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
```

You can delete the lines corresponding to the commits you don't want (e.g. c1 and c3) and then finish the rebase.

This will work fine if you really want to nuke a few commits from the `release/1.1.0` branch.  However, if you want to *temporarily* remove these commits, then you should probably create a new branch from `release/1.1.0` and work with that instead.

Note that you can also use `git revert` to "undo" a commit, but this command actually creates a **new** commit in your branch to undo what a previous commit did.  I always prefer using `rebase` to keep the history clean.

Comment: shouldn't the command be git rebase --interactive (you missed a hypen).. right ?

Comment: Hi Mate,  I think that's the sort of thing I'm after... just a question with this though - what happens when I merge the branch in again?  i.e. I pick out the commits, removing them from the branch.  When I then merge back in, does GIT see this as an action needing to be done on the original branch, or does it keep them?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 You can use either `git rebase -i` or `git rebase --interactive` ... you don't need two hyphens with the first abbreviated option.

Comment: Whatever you do to your branch (e.g. removing commits as I have described) will only affect that branch and no other ones.

Comment: yes exactly, but the answer above has written git rebase -interactive ...kindly see
@TimBiegeleisen